# rotate window based iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I am working on window based iPhone app.
I wanted to add rotation feature by using,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

but it does not work.
What is wrong with this.

Note: xCode 4 , iOS 4.3

Regards.

Comment: Where did you add this method? The app delegate or a custom view controller?

Comment: This method is added in view controller, by default.

Comment: How did you load the view controller from the app delegate?

Comment: i added it by using [window addSubview:firstView.view];. where firstView is object of FirstView class added to view based app. It is added in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions in app delegate m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 4 click on the project the very top item in the left bar and then click on the summary tab and make sure the supported orientations is set correctly.

If that is fine then you might try rewriting the return line to be something like this:

```
return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
```

If that doesn't work just try `return YES;` and see if the views will rotate.

Comment: actual problem is that, above method works fine with View based app, but it does not work with Window based app.